# Elgg: Including relationships in searches

Tags: elgg

I'm writing an Elgg plugin with two custom objects. Let's call them `DynamicThing` and `DynamicProperty`. These two objects, not surprisingly, are linked by the following Elgg relationship:

`DynamicThing` -> `HAS` ->`DynamicProperty`

`DynamicProperties` contain information specific to each `DynamicThing`; when I search for a `DynamicThing`, I therefore need to include text and data from all `DynamicProperties` belonging to it. How do I do this? I'm not finding much / any guidance in the Elgg docs anywhere.

Comment: You are aware that Elgg has system of objects and properties already implemented in form of entities and metadata, right? Why are you duplicating that?

Comment: Yes. The difference here is that our objects don't have well-known properties in advance (e.g., `thing->first_property`, `thing->second_property`, etc.) and their properties have unique sanitization and display needs. For instance, one object might have several files attached, a URL, three emails, and text fields; the next might only have a date and description. Each of these properties needs to know how to display itself, determine valid input, etc. As far as I can tell, using metadata -- the usual Elgg approach -- won't work well for our use case. Am I missing a more obvious solution?